# How can I get rid of spacing between tabular rows and columns when using colored rows?

Tags: latex, tabular

I would like to color two adjacent rows in a tabular environment with a solid color.  But when I do this, there are very small uncolored gaps between the rows and columns that are visible.  How can I get rid of these gaps?

Here's an example:

[image]

https://www.sharelatex.com/read/gnpbfsgpqwmr

Comment: Thanks!  [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373444/7407) is what I was looking for.